# Loop execution , basic branching in assembly language is sequential?

Tags: loops, assembly

A basic question regarding branching in assembly language

In assembly code

```
loop1 :
statement 1
statement 2 > BNEZ to loop2
statement 3

loop2:
statement 4
statement 5
statement 6 >BNEZ to loop1
```

In assembly language execution does completion of statement 3 automatically lead the processor to execute statement 4 (of loop2, since "loop 2" is just a label in the eyes of processor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about "assembly" in general is not really meaningful, since each architecture is a world on its own.

However, usually yes, labels are just labels, they don't impact the regular forward flow of the program - actually, the processor doesn't even get to see them, labels are just there for humans to tell the assembler how to calculate jump offsets and the like; in the resulting machine code they just don't exist.

Comment: To expand on this, a lot of beginner-written asm code does stuff like `jmp nextblock` / `nextblock: inc eax / ...`.  It's like they think they need a `jmp` to jump over the whitespace between blocks.  Even better is when it's a bug: a conditional branch that jumps the same same place as the fall-through .

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is the same as any other imperative language. Without a branching instruction, instructions are processed linearly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what an imperative language means. I am an electrical engineer and am hearing this term for first time.

Comment: Imperative languages are languages such as C, Pascal, Assembly, Fortran, etc. Instructions are executed one at a time, sequentially, unless a branching instruction is found.

Comment: You may have unexpected code paths when an observer or delegate pattern is used (which would never be found in assembly) since the high level language includes the capability for functions or methods to be called based on events that are occurring. In this cases it would not be as obvious that some other method will be called since there will be no obvious branching instruction in the high level language (though it would be there in the *compiled* byte code or machine code.